# How to join and display .shp lines with values in .dbf

Tags: qgis, dbf, attribute-joins

I've got a shapefile lines with ID attribute and .dbf with values which corresponds do ID. Every value in dbf is in different record.

I want to style lines and display label using these values from dbf. I tried to use Join tool in layer's properties in QGIS but it joined only a few of values.

[image]

---

I shown you just a simplified example...

My "real life" problem is a little bit different. I've got a shapefile with geometry of roads. Every link of the roads has a unique ID attribute. On the other hand I've got a dbf file with information about road restriction.

Structure of dbf is: **road_linkID - type - value**

```
road_link1 - max_height - 2
road_link1 - speed limit - 50
road_link1 - max_weight - 3,5
road_link2 - speedlimit - 60
road_link3 - max_weight - 3,5
road_link3 - speedlimit - 60
road_link3 - max_height - 4
```

When I'm using layer\properties\join to my road.shp adds one column with only one parameter:

```
road_link1 - max_height - 2
road_link2 - speedlimit - 60
road_link3 - max_weight - 3,5
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have the solution but something went wrong. Maybe you can provide the join / link command you used if you cant find the error yourself. If it only joined / linked a few values, you may have given the wrong data for the attributes to join or have some ghostsigns (e.g. spaces) that prevent a proper join or link.

Comment: Is the .dbf file supposed to belong to the .shp file?

Comment: it's just a simplified example....

Comment: Could you perhaps share your data so that others could test it? From the example you gave, your shapefile only contains **3 attributes** whereas your .dbf contains more (rows = features; columns = attributes). I think maybe you want to add more columns?

Comment: Here is my data: http://wikisend.com/download/158200/test.7z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to modify your .dbf file ? In your case with your simple data "join" is one to one relationship.
In my opinion it should looks like this:

[image]

And layer with lines:

[image]

Now you can make join with: Layer>Properties:

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I think it would be enough. I can't modify my dbf by hand because it's data of whole country so, it would took years to change everything. Do you know which tools I could use to modify?

Comment: Try to open and edit it with an excel app.